# ReactJs : Change style on darkMode with CreateContext

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-context

I would like to change the style of my StyledLink component when I enter in DarkMode but it doesn't works.
The value in Google Chrome developper tool never change.

I have this error too : React does not recognize the `isDarkMode` prop on a DOM element.

The console.log return me => True and 'Dark' when I click on my button to pass on dark mode so it's working well.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from '../../utils/styles/colors';
import { ThemeContext, SurveyContext } from '../../utils/styles/context/';


const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  padding: 6px 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: unset;
  border: 1px solid ${colors.primary};
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  color: ${({ isDarkMode }) => (isDarkMode ? colors.primary : '#fff')};
  background: ${({ isDarkMode }) => (isDarkMode ? 'unset' : colors.primary)};
`;




function Survey() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const isDarkMode = theme === 'dark';

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSurvey() {
      setDataLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/survey`);
        const { surveyData } = await response.json();
        setSurveyData(surveyData);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true);
      } finally {
        setDataLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchSurvey();
  }, []);

  console.log('isDarkMode:', isDarkMode);
  console.log('theme:', theme);

  return (
    <SurveyContainer>
      <QuestionTitle>Question {questionNumber}</QuestionTitle>
      {isDataLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <QuestionContent>{surveyData[questionNumber]}</QuestionContent>
      )}
      {answers && (
        <ReplyWrapper>
          <ReplyBox
            onClick={() => saveReply(true)}
            isSelected={answers[questionNumber] === true}
          >
            Oui
          </ReplyBox>
          <ReplyBox
            onClick={() => saveReply(false)}
            isSelected={answers[questionNumber] === false}
          >
            Non
          </ReplyBox>
        </ReplyWrapper>
      )}
      <LinkWrapper>
        <StyledLink
          to={`/survey/${prevQuestionNumber}`}
          $isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
        >
          Précédent
        </StyledLink>
        {surveyData[questionNumberInt + 1] ? (
          <StyledLink
            to={`/survey/${nextQuestionNumber}`}
            $isDarkMode={isDarkMode}
          >
            Suivant
          </StyledLink>
        ) : (
          <StyledLink to="/results" $isDarkMode={isDarkMode}>
            Résultats
          </StyledLink>
        )}
      </LinkWrapper>
    </SurveyContainer>
  );
}

export default Survey;
```

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const SurveyContext = createContext();
```